# Command not found error in Bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

So I have written a `bashscript.sh` file to check if a directory `project1_repo` is empty after cloning a project.

I have written four different functions to authenticate it but all the time I get `command not found` error. I have checked multiple times if there is a `syntax error` but in vain. Could someone please help me out? Thanks.

EDIT: Previously due to a typo `project1_install_dir` was called `colsim1_install_dir` but the edited version is correct.

```
#!/bin/bash

#path to install project1
function project1_install_dir() {
   while true; 
 do
  read -p "Enter FULL folder path where you want to install project1:" fullpath
  echo "you have enterd $fullpath. Please press 'y' to confirm and 'n' to enter again"
  read -p "Continue? (Y/N): " confirm 
  if [[ $confirm =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]; then
    break
  else
    continue         
  fi
done
 }

#clone project1
function clone_project1_repo() {
  git clone example git .     
    }

# four functions to Check whether cloning is successful
# function 1
function success_of_cloning_of_project1_repo3() {
  if find $fullpath/project1/project1_repo -mindepth 1 | read; then
     echo "dir not empty"
  else
     echo "dir empty"
  fi
}

# function 2
function success_of_cloning_of_project_repo2() {
DIR="$fullpath/project1/project1_repo"
if [ -n "$(ls -A $DIR)" ]; then
  echo "Take action $DIR is not Empty"
else
  echo "$DIR is Empty"
fi
}

# function 3    
function success_of_cloning_of_project_repo1() {
if [ -d $fullpath/project1/project1_repo ]; then
      [ -n "$(ls -A $fullpath/project1/project1_repo)" ] && echo "Not Empty" || echo "Empty"
else
   :
fi
    }

# function 4
function success_of_cloning_of_project_repo() {
while true;
 do
  if [ -n "$(ls -A $fullpath/project1/project1_repo)" ]; then
    echo "cloning of project1_repo is successful"               
    break
  else
    echo "cloning of project1_repo is NOT successful."
    continue      
  fi                
 done
}

#calling the functions
    function main() {
       project1_install_dir
       success_of_cloning_of_project1_repo3 
       success_of_cloning_of_project1_repo2  
       success_of_cloning_of_project1_repo1
       success_of_cloning_of_project1_repo
    }

    main
```

Terminal output:

```
jen@ex343:tdk/jen$ source bash_file_test.sh 
Enter FULL folder path where you want to install project1:/tdk/jen

you have enterd /tdk/jen. Please press 'y' to confirm and 'n' to enter again
 Continue? (Y/N): y
 You have chosen yes
-bash: success_of_cloning_of_project1_repo3: command not found
-bash: success_of_cloning_of_project1_repo2: command not found
-bash: success_of_cloning_of_project1_repo1: command not found
-bash: success_of_cloning_of_project1_repo: command not found
```

Comment: Your terminal output and the script are inconsistent. The `main()`   function calls `project1_install_dir` but  there's no such function anywhere to be found in the script. But from your output  `colsim1_install_dir` seems to be called first. Is `project1_install_dir` another script installed somewhere ? As for the output `-bash: success_of_cloning_of_colsim1_utilities_repo3:` it seems like function name got mangled with other function name.

Comment: Sorry. There was a typo..both should be project1_install_dir. I have edited. sorry again.

Comment: No problems. So far I don't see any issue related to the error itself. You have a few places where variable `$fullpath` should be quoted and `read -r -p` should be used instead of just `read -p` , but these shouldn't be the cause of the error.

Comment: Was this script ever on windows or anything that could have potentially inserted newline endings specific to DOS ? Do you use a non-English keyboard that could have entered  different types of space characters ?  I know with Chinese inputs there is a wide space character, which is different from ASCII space. Try doing `cat -A ./scriptname.sh` , maybe it will show special characters besides just `$` line ending

Comment: No, it has never been on Windows. Yes I have a German keyboard. But I don't think I've ever used any German characters. `cat -A ./scriptname.sh` didn't show any special characters than `$` signs

Comment: A [Bash function definition](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-functions/) should contain either `function` or `()`, not both. However, my Bash seems to accept it and does not complain until `success_of_cloning_of_project1_repo2`.

Answer (score 4):

Pasting your code into https://www.shellcheck.net/ reports:

```
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 7:
  read -p "Enter FULL folder path where you want to install project1:" fullpath
  ^-- SC2162: read without -r will mangle backslashes.

Line 9:
  read -p "Continue? (Y/N): " confirm
  ^-- SC2162: read without -r will mangle backslashes.

Line 26:
  if find $fullpath/project1/project1_repo -mindepth 1 | read; then
          ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
                                                         ^-- SC2162: read without -r will mangle backslashes.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
  if find "$fullpath"/project1/project1_repo -mindepth 1 | read; then

Line 36:
if [ -n "$(ls -A $DIR)" ]; then
                 ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
if [ -n "$(ls -A "$DIR")" ]; then

Line 45:
if [ -d $fullpath/project1/project1_repo ]; then
        ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
if [ -d "$fullpath"/project1/project1_repo ]; then

Line 46:
      [ -n "$(ls -A $fullpath/project1/project1_repo)" ] && echo "Not Empty" || echo "Empty"
                    ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
      [ -n "$(ls -A "$fullpath"/project1/project1_repo)" ] && echo "Not Empty" || echo "Empty"

Line 56:
  if [ -n "$(ls -A $fullpath/project1/project1_repo)" ]; then
                   ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
  if [ -n "$(ls -A "$fullpath"/project1/project1_repo)" ]; then
```

You can follow the suggestion to use `"$fullpath"` and any other recommendations in comments above. After fixing current errors  **ShellCheck** reports, it may then report additional errors when you run it again.

Comment: `sudo upvote`  **;-)**